# Is Organization Browser means Organization Chart

Tags: organization-browser, organization-profile

There is a build in web part under social called "Organization Browser". Is that same as organization chart? I added org browse web part and it only shows current user which is not my intend. I would like to create org chart based on user profile db. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but if only the current user shows, it sounds to me like you have not filled out the "Manager" field in Active Directory.